# Cardinality of the set of isolated points in a complete metric space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $X$ be a a complete metric space. Can the set of isolated points of $X$ be countably infinite?

I have proved that if $X$ were *countable* itself then it would have at least one isolated point, by *Baire Category Theorem*.

What happens when $X$ is uncountable?

$\mathbb R$ is a complete metric space with the countably infinite set of isolated points $\mathbb Z$.

So I guess the answer is *yes* , it can , But can this result be proved for arbitrary complete metric spaces?

Comment: $\Bbb Z$ is not a set of isolated points of $\Bbb R$. In fact $\Bbb R$ has no isolated points. Are you asking if every uncountable complete metric space has a subspace with countably many isolated points?

Comment: Perhaps the example you mean is something like $[-1/2,1/2]\cup\mathbb Z\subset\mathbb R$?

Comment: You don't have to create a new tag for every term appearing in your questions, by the way.

Comment: @RobArthan  :  But  if  I  take  any  point  from  $\mathbb Z$  , that  has  a  nbd  which  contains  no  other  points  from  $\mathbb  Z$  . .  So ,  how  do  I  put  that  $?$ . May  be  like   _$\mathbb Z$_  _is_  _a_  _subspace_  _every_  _point_  _of_  _which_  _is_  _a_  _isolated_  _point_  _in_  _that_  _subspace_  $?$

Comment: Big hint: what happens if you look at a _discrete metric space_ $X$ (i.e., $d(x,y)=1$ for all $x,y\in X$ with $x\neq y$)?

Comment: Yes or you could say "countably infinite subspace $\Bbb Z$ in which all points are isolated". The notion "isolated" depends on the subspace, so you need to be clear which subspace you mean.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki  Every  point  is  isolated . No  ? And  it  can  have  countable  or  uncountable  cardinality .

Comment: @user118494: Steven's comment and Alex's comment give great answers to *some* of the *many* questions you *might* be asking. Please clarify the question.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}$ is a discrete (in itself..) subspace. $S = \{\frac{1}{n}: n=1,2 \}$ is also discrete in itself, but not a discrete subspace (in a narrower sense), because $0$ is in its closure. One could say that both are discrete (in their subspace topology, all their points are isolated points of the subspace) but $\mathbb{Z}$ is both closed and discrete.

Answer (score 1):

Let $(X,d)$ be an uncountable compete metric space with no isolated points. Choose $x_0\in X$. Let $X_1=X\cup\{z_1\}$ be a metric space with metric $d_1$ defined by $$d_2(x,y)=\begin{cases}d(x,y) & x,y\neq z_1\\1+d(x_0,y) & x=z_1,y\neq z_1\\ 1+d(x,x_0) & y=z_1, x\neq z_1\\ 0 & x=y=z_1.\end{cases}$$ Then $X\subset X_1$ such that $d_1$ restricted to $X$ is $d$. We'll call this an *extension* of $X$ with an isolated point $z_1$. Now do the same extension by adding a point $z_2$ to form $X_2$. Continue this process to get $$Y=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N} X_n.$$ Call the metric inherited by $Y$ $\rho$. For each $z_i$, $\rho(x,z_i)$ is greater than 1 for all $x\neq z_i$, so $z_i$ is an isolated point. Then $Y$ is a metric space with isolated points $\{z_1,...,z_n\}$. It is only left to be shown that $Y$ is complete. Let $\{a_n\}$ be a Cauchy sequence. Fix $\varepsilon<1$. Then there exists $N$ such that for $n,m>N$, the $\varepsilon$ ball centered at $a_n$ contains also contains $a_m$. If $a_n=z_i$, then $a_m$ must also be $z_i$. Thus, either $\{a_n\}$ is constant after a while, or $\{a_{n\geq N}\}\subset X$. Since $X$ is complete, $\{a_n\}$ converges. Thus, $Y$ is a compete uncountable metric space with a countable number of isolated points.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the set $[0, 1]\cup\mathbb{Z}$ as a metric space with the usual metric. Then the set of isolated points is $\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0, 1\}$, which is countable, but the whole space is not countable.